# Why is it said that the lightest neutrino is relativistic?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, terminology, definition, neutrinos

The neutrinos from the cosmic neutrino background have a temperature of $T_\nu=1.945K$, that is an energy of $E=\frac{3}{2}k_BT_\nu$. If the neutrino's mass is around $0.1eV$

$$ \frac{3}{2}k_BT_\nu<m_\nu c^2 $$

Why it is considered relativistic if the rest mass is larger than the energy?

Comment: Can you link to a source which says this?

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2014.00030/full#:~:text=At%20the%20time%20of%20neutrino,Data%20Group)%20%5B7%5D Section 2.1, at the middle of the paragraph

Comment: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/web/viewer.html?file=../reviews/rpp2021-rev-neutrinos-in-cosmology.pdf On page 3

Comment: the first link says "some of the neutrionos may be non relativistic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From neutrino oscillation experiments, we know that there are three neutrino mass eigenstates whose masses are all different, and we know roughly the size of those differences (squared).  This sets a lower limit on the mass of the heaviest neutrino.  But we have no data on the mass of the lightest neutrino.  It is possible, for instance, that there are two massive and one massless neutrino.

Your calculation argues that at least one neutrino species should be non-relativistic at the current C$\nu$B temperature.  But the *lightest* neutrino may still be relativistic.

Comment: I thought they have to have a mass, since we can observe neutrino oscillations

Comment: @Javier Neutrino oscillation implies that the masses of the three neutrino species are all different. That means they can't *all* be zero, but there's nothing which says that *one* of them can't be.

Comment: @Javier see also this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/15483/226902

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you!